# Why do some sliders get red glow?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have following code to generate a two sliders in JS. Curiously, one slider is will have this flickering red glow when you move it, while the other does not.

[image: flickering]

What causes that and how can we avoid it?

I suspect it has something to do with the step value, as this phenomenon disappears when you delete some digits, but I couldn't figure out what it is. (This was recorded in Firefox 64.0)

```
let slider1 = makeSlider(1, 3, 0.027080502011022)

document.body.append(slider1)


let slider2 = makeSlider(0, 0.5, 0.1)

document.body.append(slider2)


function makeSlider(min, max, step) {
  let slider = document.createElement("input")
  slider.type = "range"
  slider.min = min
  slider.max = max
  slider.step = step
  return slider
}
```

In case it matters: `0.027080502011022` is what you get when you evaluate `Math.log(15)/100 - 1e-16`.

Comment: Only seems to happen on Firefox. I'm guessing it has a hard time with step values that have that much precision.

Comment: @Jeto that is what I thought too, but I also tried other values with different amounts of digits where it doesn't happen. So I'd be very interested to see what exactly is allowed and what isn't.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#step), only integer values might be allowed if min and max are ints themselves ("The default stepping value for range inputs is 1, allowing only integers to be entered, unless the stepping base is not an integer"). I'm not exactly sure I understand everything that's written there and what it implies, though.

Answer (score 1):

It would be way easier if you supplied us with the generated HTML and the accompanied CSS. Still, try:

```
input[type=range]::-moz-focus-outer { 
   border: 0; 
}
```

If not, try:

```
input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```